# Advect Particles with imported VDB velocitys

Tags: force-fields

Does the Fluid Flow Force Field support a VDB object as its Domain?
I want to advect particles based on a smoke simulation I imported from Embergen with velocities as one unified grid. I know I could also import the particles from Embergen but I would prefer this method due to easier shading and change.
Thanks for helping out.